# How to grant access to specific instances on amazon web services

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have several ec2 instances on AWS and I was wondering which is the best way to organize them in order to keep order.
As far is I know, it is not possible to group such instances e.g. with the help of a folder or something similar. So the solution I came up with is to stick to a  naming convention.
So, the names of my instances will look as follows:

- examplecustomer-ubuntu-14.0.4-t2.micro-1
- examplecustomer-ubuntu-14.0.4-t2.micro-2
- examplecustomer1-ubuntu-14.0.4-t2.micro-1
- examplecustomer1-ubuntu-14.0.4-t2.micro-2

Now I have several users/customers which should just see specific instances (e.g. customer1 should only see instances starting with examplecustomer1).
Therefore, I created a policy and attached it to the user. My idea was to use a wildcard within the ARN-Resourcepath, but that doesn´t seem to work.
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

**Example policy:**

```
  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1443859866333",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/customer1*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was unable to find a solution by follogwing the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-ec2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't completey hide the instances as of yet using IAM Policies. You certainly can restrict what users can do on the instances, either as you have suggested above, or by 'tagging' the instances and grant priviliges to specific users based on those tags.

You might find this blog article useful:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2KPWZJJ4S26H6/Demystifying-EC2-Resource-Level-Permissions

Also this:

> Currently, the Amazon EC2 ec2:Describe* API actions do not support
>   resource-level permissions, so you cannot control which individual
>   resources users can view in the console. Therefore, the * wildcard is
>   necessary in the Resource element of the above statement. For more
>   information about which ARNs you can use with which Amazon EC2 API
>   actions, see Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API
>   Actions.

From here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful.